# How to pass a 2 dimensional array value in a swift mailer setTo function

Tags: php, symfony, multidimensional-array, swiftmailer

I am getting a 2 dimensional array value as a result after a for loop.The value is `$chunk[$i][$j]`.And when I passed that value into setTo function,
the error showing as

`Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in H:\xampp
    \htdocs\sngmarket\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers
\MailboxHeader.php line 350`.

How do I solve this?.Here my code

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT u.emailaddress FROM AcmeRegistrationBundle:userlist u");
   $grp_emails[] = $query->getResult();

   $chunk = array_chunk($grp_emails, 10);
   $get_chunk_count = count($chunk);

   for($i=0;$i<$get_chunk_count;$i++)
   {
    $count_inside_count = count($chunk[$i]);
      for($j=0;$j<=$count_inside_count;$j++)
      {
        $mails=$chunk[$i][$j];

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
          ->setSubject('Hello Email')
          ->setFrom('marketplace@socialnetgate.com')
          ->setTo($mails)
          ->setReturnPath('gowtham@ephronsystems.com')
          ->setBody('Hello World');

          $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
          return array();
      }
   }
```

Comment: may you var_dump your `$chunk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this.

Have you looked at the documentation on how to send batch emails WITHOUT recipients being aware of each other? In your snippet each email contains up to 10 recipients, which may be better then sending all recipients, but still is pretty bad.

Have a look at [Sending emails in batch](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#sending-emails-in-batch) and also at the [plugins](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html) to make sure you don't reach the limit of emails you are allowed to send in a certain time frame.